# Mockito returning a value getting updated on the fly

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am trying to test a class using Mockito.

```
@Mock otherClassMock;
Myclass ob = new Myclass(otherClassMock, ...)

@Test
void test() {
  ob.setParam(5);
  when(otherClassMock.otherMethod()).thenReturn(ob.getParam());
  ob.myMethod();// internally updates Param and calls otherObject.otherMethod()
}
```

Now `myMethod()` internally changes value of `Param` and calls `otherMethod()` , but `thenReturn()` returns the old value of 5. Is there a way to get the updated value in the `thenReturn()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do what you want.  It's called an `Answer`, which is a way of specifying a method to run when a mock is used, instead of specifying just a return value.  Even a simple lambda expression can be used as an `Answer`.

The code that you've written evaluates `ob.getParam()`, and passes the result to `thenReturn`, which is not what you want.  You want something like this.

```
when(otherClassMock.otherMethod()).thenAnswer(invocation -> ob.getParam());
```

This way, `ob.getParam()` will be evaluated at the time that `otherClassMock.otherMethod()` is called.